# Heaviside function and weak solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

If a solution to a PDE has a solution f(x) in which f(x) is a Heaviside function, independent on its argument, can I say the solution is unstable, therefore being weak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Since the PDE has a solution that depends on a Heaviside function, it is discontinous in some parts of its domain, therefore it is not smooth. Being so, the solution does not pass on the stability criteria for a classical (or strong) solution, and so the solution is weak.